# IE js (CSS, API, error, ...) только для IE10..11only не зависящее от эмуляции / режима документа

Tags: javascript, css, api, internet-explorer, кроссбраузерность

Привет из прошлого )))

Ищу CSS или API или ещё что-то только для **IE10..11real не зависящее от режима документа** / эмуляции

Например,
document.documentMode (IE8..11) - работает в любом режиме документа (IE5..11), можно использовать для определения реальных IE5..7

```
if (document.documentMode) {alert ("IE8..11real");}
```

или

window.performance (IE9..11) - работает в любом режиме документа (IE5..11), можно использовать для определения реальных IE5..8

```
if (window.performance) {alert ("IE9..11real");}
```

Есть что-то подобное для IE10..11?

```
if (...) {alert ("IE10..11real");}
```

Answer (score 1):

Пока лучший способ ScriptEngineMajorVersion + ScriptEngineMajorVersion
Похожий на условную компиляцию @_jscript_version (условная компиляция в IE11 не работает)

По данным из https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript

```
if("ScriptEngineMajorVersion" in window){
//if(ScriptEngineMajorVersion()==1){alert ("IE3");};
//else if(ScriptEngineMajorVersion()==3){alert ("IE4");};
if(ScriptEngineMajorVersion()==5){
    if(ScriptEngineMinorVersion()==0){alert ("IE5");}
    else if(ScriptEngineMinorVersion()==1){alert ("IE5.01");}
    else{alert ("IE"+ScriptEngineMinorVersion());};}
    //JScript 5.8 ещё и в IE6 Mobile
else{alert ("IE"+ScriptEngineMajorVersion());};};
```

Для IE10..11

```
if("ScriptEngineMajorVersion" in window){
    if(ScriptEngineMajorVersion()>9){
    alert ("IE10..11real");};};
```